# Intercept http requests on react native?

Tags: react-native, http

I would like to intercept all http requests and responses from react native context. In nodejs I like to use [yesno](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yesno-http) which wraps the nodejs http module. Is there an equivalent way to do this in react native? Any libraries exist for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[React native provides the `fetch, XMLHttpRequest and WebSocket` as it's primary primitives for doing all networking](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network). You can intercept all responses by doing something like

```js
const oldFetch = fetch
fetch = async (...args) => {
  console.log('fetch was called', args)
  const response = await oldFetch(...args)
  return response
}

const OldWebSocket = WebSocket
WebSocket = class extends OldWebSocket {
  constructor(...args) {
    console.log('WebSocket was called', args)
    super(...args)
  }
}


const OldXMLHttpRequest = XMLHttpRequest
XMLHttpRequest = class extends OldXMLHttpRequest {
  open(...args) {
    console.log('XMLHttpRequest.open was called', args)
    return super.open(...args)
  }
  send(...args) {
    console.log('XMLHttpRequest.send was called', args)
    return super.send(...args)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I use [apisauce](https://npmjs.com/package/apisauce), so far it worked well for me, you can add monitors and transforms for requests and responses

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yeah that's not what I'm really looking for - it doesn't actually intercept all http requests. It's just a lib for marking http requests